# Disable a drop down and still submit a value?

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down box that I would like to lock after an item has been selected. Unfortunately using 'disable' stops the field from being submitted at all when the form is submitted. Is there a way around this?

Comment: place some div on the top of select box BTW where is code..

Comment: please provide html and code. :)

Comment: set the value of a hidden field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can re-enable the dropdown list right before the form is submitted:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("#yourDropdown").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: Simple and straight forward!

Answer (score 5):

Take a hidden field:

```
<input id="hiddenSelect" type="hidden" name="same_as_select_box">
```

Then in select change event set the value to that hidden field like following:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  $('#hiddenSelect').val(this).val();
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Now you can submit the form with your select value, without further enabling it at submit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually this does work for me, and it's not really fair as you didn't know, but I couldn't assign to a random hidden variable as the form element is part of a RoR model. I would have had to remove the form element first which would have been a lot of work.